# How to drag button on screen and give translate animation from current position to original position?

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to translate animation perform on button. Here Buttons are drag able in layout. I drag the button on any place of screen and when I remove my touch,I want to perform transform animation from current drop able points of button to original place which is initially button located on the screen. if any one have idea then well come.

Comment: I still have a problem with coordinate of start animation to end animation

Comment: What kind of problem? Could you please edit the code you are using into your question so I can see what you are doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can animate any `View` very simply with a [**View Property Animator**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) like this:

```
button.animate().translationX(deltaX)
                .translationY(deltaY)
                .setDuration(duration);
```

This works on API level 11 and above. If it is supposed to work before API level 11 then you need to use [**View Animations**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html):

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(fromX, toX, fromY, toY);
animation.setDuration(duration);
button.startAnimation(animation);
```

If you have any further question feel free to ask.